# how to get statistics of received packets on a specific udp port

Tags: linux, networking, udp

my linux pc has a udp port listening, however, the application does not seem to receive any packets from this port. Is there any tool that I can use to show the number of packets received on this port?

Comment: Note that any answers about iptables assume that you have iptables running, which is probably likely, but not guaranteed.

Answer (score 3):

Use `tcpdump`. For example, on my machine, the interface I'm looking for the traffic on is eth0, and in this case I'm checking port 123.

```
jed@myhost:~$ sudo tcpdump -nei eth0 udp port 123
```

If you don't know what the interfaces on your machine are, you can get them with `ifconfig -a` or `ip link` (either might require sudo, depending on your permissions).

Answer (score 2):

You can log them using iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -j LOG --log-prefix "udp connection: "
```

Comment: Thanks. But I get the following result "iptables: No chain/target/match by that name." what is wrong?

Comment: It sounds like iptables is disabled on your server.  What distribution are you using?

Comment: it is centos 6. iptables is there. but when i use the command "iptables -A INPUT -j LOG", it will complain: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name." what is special with LOG target?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want counters for a particular protocol, then you can create an iptables rule to accept those packets, and it will keep track of how many packets and bytes matched the rule.

If you wanted to match packets on UDP port 44, the iptables command would look like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 44 -j ACCEPT
```

If you want more details about those packets, then as Jed Daniels has said, `tcpdump` is gonna be your best bet.

```
tcpdump -nei eth0 udp port 44
```